# Using an "AND" query with Lucene

Tags: search, lucene.net

I'm very new to Lucene.net (2.9.4), and I'm attempting to search using a MultiFieldQueryParser.  I'm not getting the results back I expect.  I've searched for answers to no avail...wonder if someone can assist...

Take the following records (strings) of items that have been indexed:

- Medical Advisory Board Bios
- Medical Advisory Board
- A presentation - Speaker Bios

When I search for:
**advisory**, I'd expect to get 1 & 2 back, which I do.
When I search for **advisory AND bios**, I'd expect to get just 1 back, but it seems to be treating the AND as an or and I get all three results back...

What am I missing about the AND? The docs seem to say you can do this straight-forward out of the box.  Thanks for the help...

Comment: After spending hours on this yesterday, I just tried it again, and it worked.  Seems as if it requires capital letters for boolean operators, which I'm quite positive I was testing with, but, I must not have been.  Hope this helps seomeone else...

Comment: **http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean operators**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours on this yesterday, I just tried it again, and it worked. Seems as if it requires capital letters for boolean operators, which I'm quite positive I was testing with, but, I must not have been. Hope this helps seomeone else...